# Trying to prove that derivative is increasing and then decreasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the function to be unimodal, I have found the derivative of the distribution which is:
$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = x^{(a-2)}[(a-1)- ax]\ $

All I am stuck with is in showing that the function increases and then decreases.
Thanks!

Comment: I found somewhere,that because it has one sign change, it is unimodal. But wouldn't there be two cases, one when a < 2 and other when a > 2

Comment: Can you make any statements about the second derivative?

Comment: For a function to increase and then decrease, it means that it reaches a maximum. And what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a maximum?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Maximum generally occurs at mean.

Comment: No, this presupposes symmetry. Forget that this is a density, think of it as just any function of which you want to find its maximum

Comment: Just find the roots of the $derivative=0$. If there is only one root than there is only 1 extremum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming that $a>0$. Assume for the moment that $x>0$. Then the only zero of the derivative is at $x=\frac{a-1}a=1-\frac1a$. If $0<x<1-\frac1a$, then $ax<a-1$, so $(a-1)-ax>0$; $x^{a-2}>0$ as well, so the derivative is positive, and $f$ is increasing. If $x>1-\frac1a$, then by a similar calculation $(a-1)-ax<0$, and $x^{a-2}$ is still positive, so the derivative is negative, and $f$ is decreasing. Thus, $f$ has a local maximum at $x=1-\frac1a$.

If $a>2$, the derivative has another zero at $x=0$. However, for negative $x$ the power $x^{a-2}$ is in general undefined, so I’m guessing that either your function is defined only for non-negative $x$, in which case there’s nothing more to check.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yes the function is defined for $0\leq x \leq 1$. I have a doubt that would the zero not exist when $x^{(a-2)}=0$ (which I think you considered in the case when $a>2$). Are we assuming in the first case that $0 < a< 2$, where it is clear that zero exist at $x=\frac{a-1}{a}$

Comment: @user30438: For all $a>0$ there’s a zero at $x=\frac{a-1}a$; for $a>2$ there’s also one at $x=0$, but it corresponds to the minimum at $x=0$, so it doesn’t matter.

Comment: should not a be greater than 1, otherwise x could take negative values as we want $(a-1)-ax > 0 $

Comment: @user30438: If $0<a\le 2$, $a-2\le 0$, and $0^{a-2}$ is undefined, i.e., the derivative is undefined at $0$. Thus, you get that second zero (at $x=0$) only when $a>2$.

Comment: The point I am making is that for $(a−1)−ax>0$, shouldn't a>1, or else how would it be > 0 .

Comment: @user30438: Oh, I see. It would still be $0$ when $x=\frac{a-1}a$; it’s just that in that case $x$ itself is negative. When I wrote that, I wasn’t yet absolutely certain where $f$ was supposed to be defined; now that I know for sure that it’s on $[0,1]$, I agree that we need to have $a\ge 1$.